# Blender 2.82, two GPU but only one render in Cycle

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, performance

I'm not sure is this should be like that but, I have two GTX 970 graphic cards...and when I try to render something in cycles, I've notice that only one GPU works about 30-40 % and second one stays on 0%.

I'm little bit confused because I see two tiles in render window....

See screenshots below....

Any idea how to use full potential I have in my PC?[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Try to adjust the threads count to 2 manually. It appers at the bottom of your second picture.

Comment: Nope....same thing...one GPU ~ 40%, second one = 0% :(

Comment: Any ideas??? Someone.....????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I get as an answer on Reddit....I think this info will be useful for others.

Windows Task manager does not report multiple GPU correctly. Use a free app called CPUID HWmonitor. Everything else looks good. Make sure you have the latest Nvidia gfx drivers for your GPUs installed.

https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/156780/en-us